# How to generate a lot of tables from SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following tables:

Table names: US states - 50 tables with following format

1. columns: state, zip code, address
2. zip code is not unique

I want to do the following with one SQL query:

1. generate a list of unique zip codes ~40,000
2. create tables with names of the zip code ~40,000
3. in each table - only the records with corresponding zip code
4. columns: state, zip code, address

How to create such a SQL query to be most effective and cheapest way to create all these tables?

Comment: `How to create such a SQL query ...` - Reality is - there is no way to accomplish this with just one simple and cheap query. some scripting should be involved to orchestrate all above. Meantime, that design sounds terrible to me from so many different prospective. I feel this is a dead end honestly. You should revisit your design. Mostly, what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Why you need 40K tables? etc.

Comment: that design is what is needed from me and it is just OK with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current features you could do a couple "cheats":

- Define a linear transform from zipcode to dates. For example, DATE_ADD('1980-01-01', INTERVAL zipcode DAYS)
- Create a partitioned table - use that synthetic date as partition.
- Write a query that inserts all your data into that table ``` SELECT *, synthetic_date(zipcode) FROM ``tables*`` ```.
- Now you have a partitioned table, with each partition containing data only for each zip code! Cost is linear, just one scan of all your data.
- And if you'd like, now you can copy each partition to a new table - at no cost (but be aware of daily quotas). See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_a_single_partition.

Comment: note: Maximum number of partitions per partitioned table — 4,000

Comment: So the possible solutions:
1) copy each partition to new table - with 40,000 tables I have to deal with daily limits.
2) I cannot have 40,000 partitions.

What is the solution?

About the daily limits: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#export_jobs
I don't see what daily quotas are related to 1).

Comment: I see a possible solution as follows:
1) generate 50 tables for each state. 
2) generate partitions inside each one for the zip codes.

40,000/50 = 800 partitions per state can deal with the 4,000 partitions per table limit. The only problem - daily quotas - where is this info relevant to the case?

Comment: I see this limit: :Maximum number of partition modifications per day per table — 5,000
You are limited to a total of 5,000 partition modifications per day for a partitioned table. " If I do 800 partitions in each of these 50 tables I suppose will be fine with this limit?